# Pulsar backlog message count always returned as zero

Tags: apache-pulsar, pulsar

I want to know the number of messages in a pulsar partitioned topic that isn't picked up by any of the consumers yet. My application is in python so I am using the REST APIs. I tried both `/admin/v2/persistent/public/default/{topic-name}/backlog` and `/admin/v2/persistent/public/default/{topic-name}/stats` endpoints.

Both APIs always return message backlog as zero even when I have unacknowledged messages in the topic.

How can I get unacknowledged message count on a pulsar topic?

Answer (score 1):

For partitioned pulsar topics, you have to use partition name instead of the topic name in admin APIs.
Using `/admin/v2/persistent/public/default/{partitioned-topic}/stats` gives the topic status including message backlog